# Group objects by one of its params with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, lodash

Basically I would want to transform this

```
[
  { key: 0, name: 'Some name' },
  { key: 0, name: 'Some name' },
  { key: 1, name: 'Some name' },
  { key: 1, name: 'Some name' },
]
```

To this where every object with the key of  0 would go into the first array and every object with the key of 1 would go into the second array.

```
[
  [
    { key: 0, name: 'Some name' },
    { key: 0, name: 'Some name' },
  ],
  [
    { key: 1, name: 'Some name' },
    { key: 1, name: 'Some name' },
  ],
];
```

Would really not mind using lodash for this but couldn't find the correct array method.

Comment: And you have at least tried to accomplish your goal by yourself? Can you share your attempt with us?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd solve it with `reduce`:

```js
const firstArray = [
  { key: 0, name: 'Some name' },
  { key: 0, name: 'Some name' },
  { key: 1, name: 'Some name' },
  { key: 1, name: 'Some name' },
]

const secondArray = firstArray.reduce((acc, elem) => {
  acc[elem.key] = [...(acc[elem.key] || []), elem];
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(secondArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for this purpose

lodash offers the [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) function which suits this application nicely.

For example:

```js
let a = [
  { key: 0, name: 'Some name' },
  { key: 0, name: 'Some name' },
  { key: 1, name: 'Some name' },
  { key: 1, name: 'Some name' },
];

let res = Object.values(a.reduce((acc, r) => { 
    acc[r.key] = (acc[r.key] || []).concat([r]);
    return acc;
}, {}));


console.log("Result:",res);


// You can also use lodash groupBy (which is more concise)
console.log("Using lodash:",Object.values(_.groupBy(a, "key")))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Really like this lodash solution.

Comment: It's nice.. the whole library is very useful!

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [
  { key: 0, name: 'Some name' },
  { key: 0, name: 'Some name' },
  { key: 1, name: 'Some name' },
  { key: 1, name: 'Some name' },
];
array.sort(function(a,b){return a.key - b.key})
var temp = array[0].key;
var newArray = [];
var tempArray =[];
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(temp != array[i].key){
        newArray.push(tempArray);
        tempArray =[];
        temp = array[i].key;
    }
    tempArray.push(array[i]);
}
newArray.push(tempArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function groupData(){
       var mainArray = [
        { key: 0, name: 'Some name' },
        { key: 0, name: 'Some name' },
        { key: 1, name: 'Some name' },
        { key: 1, name: 'Some name' },
      ];  
      
      var unique = [...new Set(mainArray.map(item => item.key))];
       var tempArrays = new Array(parseInt(unique.length));   
       for(var k = 0; k < unique.length; k++){
        if(! tempArrays[k] ){
         tempArrays[k] = [];
        }
         
          for(var i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++){
      if (mainArray[i].key == unique[k]){          
              tempArrays[k].push(mainArray[i]);
             }
          }  
        }
        console.log(tempArrays);
    }
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="groupData();" value="Group Data">
```

Comment: Why Jquery? It is not needed to create a simple groupBy method.

Comment: It's not required, just remove document.ready function and you can do the same thing with plain JavaScript. Use same logic in any function.

Comment: I don't know your exact scenario, how you want to call this function. So for easiness I kept it on load and for that used jQuery.

Comment: I have removed jQuery from my answer, it will work with no any additional js.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply looping over your existing array and pushing the results to a newly created multidimensional array. This is, in my opinion, is the most readable way.

```js
const mainArray = [
  { key: 0, name: 'Some name' },
  { key: 0, name: 'Some name' },
  { key: 1, name: 'Some name' },
  { key: 1, name: 'Some name' },
];

// create an empty array to store our results
const result = [];

mainArray.forEach(x => {
  const key = x.key;
  // Instantiate a new array if it does not exist 
  // for the given key.
  if (!result[key]) {
   result[key] = [];
  }
  
  // push the object to the array
  result[key].push(x)
});

console.log(result);
```